# sqlite3 behavior comparing time(string)s

Tags: sqlite, timestamp

I am trying to select all times after a given time:

```
SELECT created FROM table WHERE created >= '2014-11-11 00:00:00';
```

but I get back results including:

```
2014-11-6
2014-11-3
ect..
```

which prompted me to do some tests which confused me:

```
SELECT '2014-11-11' < '2014-11-3';
1
sqlite> SELECT DATETIME('2014-11-11') < '2014-11-3';
1
sqlite> SELECT DATETIME('2014-11-11') < '2014-11-03';
0
sqlite> SELECT DATETIME('2014-11-11') < DATETIME('2014-11-3');
;;no result
```

it seems that sqlite cannot compare two datetime and using any other combination results in two strings being compared which is not what I want. Which leads me to the question:

**How does sqlite3 behave towards 'timestamps' and how to store and compare them properly so that they behave as one would expect?**

I am using Ubuntu Linux 14.04 with `sqlite3 3.8.2 2013-12-06 14:53:30`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `timestamp` type in SQLite. So, all of your tests are string comparison: `DATETIME('2014-11-11')` returns `2014-11-11 00:00:00`, and `DATETIME('2014-11-3')` returns `null` since `2014-11-3` is not a format that `DATETIME` understands. Your last case return `null`, but not `no result`.
If you want to SQLite compare your timestamps properly, than you should store them in sortable format: `2014-11-03` instead of `2014-11-3`. And if you want to use [SQLite date and time functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html), than that should be format that them understands.